# How to make menu hierarchy flowchart in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, tree

I am trying to make a hierarchical tree like this, [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnEOf.png)

I have designed the basic tree, but I am unable to find a way to draw the lines, connecting the parent and child entries in the menu.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QJ8q.png)

Does anyone know a better way, or literally any way to draw the lines?

Answer (score 0):

I wish I could see some code to see how that's implemented. What about adding borders on divs? Like just a border-left? I'm sorry if I'm missing the question, I'd need more info. I hope this helps. If you share a live code I may be able to work on it live and test some things.